# javascript some how stop working

Tags: javascript

earler this code work fine.but don't know suddenly stop working..after changing location for code.

```
give error :  
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined (in chrome)
- no element found (in firefox)

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("select"); //get array of select tag

var sSrnti = inputs[0].options[inputs[0].selectedIndex].value; //get selected value of first list

var sType = inputs[1].options[inputs[1].selectedIndex].value;//get selected value of second list

var sStatus = inputs[2].options[inputs[2].selectedIndex].value;//get selected value of third list
```

please help me..
Thanks

Comment: Where do you move the code from and where did you put it?

Comment: At least one of `inputs[0]`, `inputs[1]`, `inputs[2]` appears to yield `null`. I'm guessing that the elements do not exist in the DOM at the time or context where the code is being executed.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is that you've moved your script above your actual html. This would cause it to run before your dom tree is loaded, thus returning ``undefined`` for ``document.getElementsByTagName("select");``, causing the error on the next line.

Comment: wrapping the reference within window.onload can save you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by

```
"after changing location for code"
```

You should be more clear on that. But as kippie commented above, you have most likely moved the script tag that calls your js file above the html.
Here's the recommended layout for html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>some title</title>
        <!-- add all refs to css files here taking note of the cascading property of css-->
        <link href="..." rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
    <!-- add all calls to js files here, so you can be sure dom is loaded-->
    <script src="somefile.js"></script>
</html>
```

If you have done this and the problem is still there, let me know what code you moved and where you moved it to.
You can also use the chrome console to try getting a hold of the code. e.g

```
press control + shift + j on your keyboard
```

and use the same commands eg document.getElementByID('#id') to see if that would work, then we can see what's wrong.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a select element that looks like this:

```
<select id="ddlViewBy">
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Running this code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Would make strUser be 2. If what you actually want is test2, then do this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either there are not at least three `select` elements in your HTML or your JavaScript is firing before the DOM has loaded.

Try the following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
    // Your JavaScript here...
   }
</script>
```